# Firebase setting user data on registration

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I want to create an new user in my firebase. This is the code I´m using:

```
function createUser(email, password, username) {
        ref.createUser({
            email: email,
            password: password
        }, function(error) {
            if (error === null) {
                $activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
                $scope.padding_error = null;
                $scope.error = null;
                logUserIn(email, password);
            } else {
                $activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
                console.log(error.code);
                switch (error.code) {
                    case "INVALID_EMAIL":
                        $scope.padding_error = "10";
                        $scope.error = "Falsche E-Mail Adresse oder falsches Passwort";
                        $scope.$apply();
                    case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                        $scope.padding_error = "10";
                        $scope.error = "Falsche E-Mail Adresse oder falsches Passwort";
                        $scope.$apply();
                    case "EMAIL_TAKEN":
                        $scope.padding_error = "10";
                        $scope.error = "Diese E-Mail Adresse ist schon registriert";
                        $scope.$apply();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to store the username in addition to email and password somewhere in my firebase. How is this possible instantly after user registration?

Comment: A good place to start would be the guide on authentication, which includes a short example of [storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the registration is succesful you can simply push the email and password variables to firebase. See code below.

```
function createUser(email, password, username) {
        ref.createUser({
            email: email,
            password: password
        }, function(error) {
            if (error === null) {
                ... Registration successful
                $activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
                $scope.padding_error = null;
                $scope.error = null;
                ##NEWCODE HERE##
                emailRef = new Firebase("<YOURFIREBASEURL>/accounts/"+username+"/email")
                passRef = new Firebase("<YOURFIREBASEURL>/accounts/"+username+"/password")
                emailRef.set(email)
                passRef.set(password)
                logUserIn(email, password);
            } else {
                ... Something went wrong at registration
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: But most likely, you would want to create the user record after logging in. Security rules will probably be in place (if they aren't, they should be) to prevent anonymous write. [AngularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) has some great examples of this strategy.